# What do I need to install to use OraOLEDB

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado

I have a Delphi 2007 app using ADO to connect to an Oracle database.  I have found for the app to support Blob field types I need to use the OraOLEDB provider to connect.  The connection string:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=pwd;User ID=username;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Persist Security Info=False
```

I have found that using MSDAORA.1 as the provider, while it works with all other database communication, does not work with the Blob field.

My question is, what do I need to install to have OraOLEDB installed/supported?  Is there a specific DLL that needs to reside?

I have found the typical Oracle client installation is not supporting OraOLEDB.  It errors when trying to connect to the database because OraOLEDB is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Download OraOLEDB_90101.exe and run it.  The full instructions are [Instructions for Installing Oracle Provider for OLE DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/ole_db/htdocs/install9i.htm)
.  If you do some searching on MSDN they say that BLOB data is not supported with the Microsoft data provider, MSDAORA.1

Comment: will give this a try with my customer tomorrow - will let you know.

Comment: Where do you download the file??  I was just on the Oracle site and searched for OraOLEDB_90101.exe.  Could not find a link to download this file.

Comment: disregard - google searching did better job than Oracles against their own site:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/ole_db/htdocs/utilsoft.htm

Comment: Google is WAY WAY better at search than Oracle!  Sorry it took me so long to get back and check for comments on this.

Comment: It actually turned out to be this file: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/ole_db/htdocs/utilsoft.htm  The client for Oracle 10g.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Those urls are no longer valid. Does anyone have working one?