# Delphi 7 and oracle (oraoledb)

Tags: delphi

I developed an application that uses Delphi 7, ADO and ORACLE, the provider I use is OraOLEDB.
What do I need to install to connect to oracle server. (list apps or drivers please)

OS : Win7 64x
Delphi : 7

I installed OraOLEDB_90101 from Oracle site. so I can see OraOLEDB in adoConnection in delphi.
I define TNS_Admin in environment variables (system & user) : D:\oracle\ora90\network\ADMIN
my tnsnames.ora is :

```
DS2 =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.1.254.50)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = ict)
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
)
)
```

I also define "10.1.254.50  ds2" in hosts (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc).
I can "tnsping ds2" in command prompt but whenever I add ADOConnection in a form and set the connectionString to : "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=tehranvu;Data Source=ds2" and select connect to TRUE, the error message raises : "ORA 12154: TNS: could not resolve service name.".
I created a UDL file and the "test Connection" is OK. (copying the connection string from udl file doesn't work) !!!!

I set connection string to :

```
"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Persist Security Info=True;
 UserId=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Data       Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = 
 (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DS2)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = ict)(SERVER = 
 DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DS2)))"
```

But it raises the same error!!!

What other apps or drivers should I install (for example Oracle Client, ...) to resolve "service name" in delphi?

Comment: My guess is the `OraOLEDB` provider has a problem with `host` and `service_name` having the same name. Can you try to rename one of both?

Comment: My Main question is : Do I have to install Oracle Client or not ? if yes, what version? (win 7 64x & delphi 7)...

Comment: You need to have installed either the `Oracle Client` or at least `ODAC`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179194/deploy-application-with-oraoledb-provider/2183493#2183493) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884183/what-do-i-need-to-install-to-use-oraoledb)

Answer (score 0):

Try

- Paste your code from UDL file to the connection string.
- configure ODBC provider.